# Relative position unreliable on embedded view

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

[image]I have a viewcontroller. On my storyboard I have dragged a TextField onto it.
In my code, I define a rect, that needs to be positioned relative to the text field, as follows:

```
CGRect autocompleteRect = CGRectMake(schoolField.frame.origin.x, schoolField.frame.origin.y + 70, schoolField.frame.size.width,autocompleteTableView.contentSize.height);
```

That works fine, until I embed my TextField in a UIView.
The UIView itself is managed by auto layout to be positioned in the center of the Controllers .view.

I would say, that this should not be of any influence to the relative postion of my rect. However, it is:

Since the embedding of the TextField in a UIView, my rect is positioned differently, also depending on the screen size of the device I'm running it on.

So, I guess it's got something to do with AutoLayout,but I wouldn't know what I should tell my app to behave the way I want it to.

Thanks for your insights.

Comment: Can you show more code for detail ? How did you add `TextField` to `UIView`?

Comment: I selected the TextField in IB, and chose Editor>Embed In>View.
The TextField doesn't have any constraints within
 the UIView

Comment: And what is your UIView and can you show storyboard file?

Comment: `TextField` have wrong position because at first, `TextField` has a frame which relates with `UIViewController`'s `view`. This frame on `UIView` will be different

Comment: @ trungduc: I deleted TextField and dragged a new TextField ("schoolField") onto the View. It is still showing the same behavior.

Comment: You said `That works fine, until I embed my TextField in a UIView`. What is your `UIView` on image. I want to know where you want to add TextField exactly

Comment: do you want me create a discussion for us?

Comment: The View I added is called "Credentials Container". The textField should be on the Credentials Container. I think that's what I did. However, depending on the screen size, the actual text field is positioned correctly, but the programmatically defined rect is not.

Comment: Let's chat in discussion

Comment: I think you should create constraint for your TextField. It's better way

Comment: can i add an answer for your question? ;)

Comment: Oh please. I will remove mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`autocompleteRect` is a rect inside `CredentialsContainer`, but you use it for a view which has been contained by `UIViewController`'s `view`. That's why your `autocompleteRect` has wrong position when you use.

To solve issue, you need to add the view which will use `autocompleteRect` to `CredentialsContainer`.

Hope this can make you more clearly.